# Returned value after reading text file in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, readfile

What do i get when i read a text file(notepad file)? I'm guessing it returns a string after reading the text file? I want to be able to index the returned value, for example, i want to use text.indexOf() to get a specific value in the returned values
i'm using node.js

```
const fs = require('fs')
function readText(filepath){
    var text = fs.readFileSync(filepath, 'utf8');
    return text;
}
```

Comment: "i want to use text.indexOf() to get a specific value in the returned values". So what are you waiting for?

Comment: Good question ^^

Comment: but i cant, thats why i'm asking what type of data i'm getting

Comment: Why can't you? Are you getting an error? Add all the details to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The function fs.readFileSync as you have used it will return the contents of the file as a string.

You can find the documentation for readFileSync and other fs api's here: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options

It's often helpful to experiment with code snippets like this in a REPL, by adding `console.log` statements or pausing in a debugger to better understand what is happening.